# How to use custom tile sources (Bing, Google) in geoviews / holoviews?

Tags: python, holoviews, geoviews

Geoviews offers a number of predefined tile sources, such as EsriImagery. These tile sources can be used as background imagery in interactive maps, e.g.:

```py
import geoviews as gv
import holoviews as hv
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
from pyproj import Transformer

crs_proj = "epsg:4326"
crs_wgs = "epsg:3857"

# custom map bounds
lim_lng_max = 8.728187
lim_lng_min = 8.707770
lim_lat_max = 49.413423
lim_lat_min = 49.406589

# define reverse projection
proj_transformer_back = Transformer.from_crs(
    crs_proj, crs_wgs, always_xy=True)

gg_bottomleft = proj_transformer_back.transform(
    lim_lng_min, lim_lat_min)
gg_topright = proj_transformer_back.transform(
    lim_lng_max, lim_lat_max)

def set_active_tool(plot, element):
    # enable wheel_zoom by default
    plot.state.toolbar.active_scroll = plot.state.tools[0]
    
gv_layers = (
        gv.tile_sources.EsriImagery.opts(alpha=1.0) * \
        gv.Points(
            (xy_list[1][0], xy_list[1][1]), 
            label='Points Layer', 
            crs=ccrs.UTM(zone='32N')).opts(
                size=5, color='white', alpha=0.25)
    ).opts(
        responsive=True,
        title=f"Heidelberg Map with EsriImagery background",
        hooks=[set_active_tool],
        data_aspect=1,
        xlim=(gg_bottomleft[0],gg_topright[0]),
        ylim=(gg_bottomleft[1],gg_topright[1])
    )
# save to HTML
hv.save(gv_layers, f'heidelberg_map.html', backend='bokeh')
```

How can existing tile sources be extended, e.g. by Google Maps or Bing Maps Imagery?

Answer (score 3):

Custom tile Sources can be constructed using `WMTS` from `geoviews.element`. See the examples in [tile_sources.py](https://github.com/holoviz/geoviews/blob/master/geoviews/tile_sources.py).

There are two types of Tile-URIs supported: {Q}-Format and {X}{Y}{Z} Format (note the capital letters).

Two examples for Bing Maps and Google Maps Imagery:

```py
from geoviews.element import WMTS
BingMapsImagery = WMTS(
    'http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{Q}.jpeg?g=1',
    name="BingMapsImagery")
GoogleMapsImagery = WMTS(
    'https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={X}&y={Y}&z={Z}',
    name="GoogleMapsImagery")
```